# Why is the order of factors (order of samples in dataset) affect PERMANOVA results with adonis2?

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis, permutation-test, vegan

I am trying to run PERMANOVA tests on multiomics datasets collected from coral samples using adonis2 (v 2.6-5). I found when the order of samples in my dataset change, the pvalues change, sometimes significantly. For instance, I have 4 time points (0, 1, 3, 5), and if the order of samples is 0, 1, 3, 5 the PERMANOVA results are different than if the samples are ordered TP 1, 3, 5, 0.

I have made sure the order of the samples in the sample information with the factors (master dataframe) match the sample order in the data frame, both below for reference. The data frame has the samples as rows and transcript names as columns.[image: t.filtered.data dataframe]
[image: "master" dataframe]

When the samples are in this order the PERMANOVA results are as follows.

```
Permutation test for adonis under reduced model
Terms added sequentially (first to last)
Blocks:  strata 
Permutation: free
Number of permutations: 999

adonis2(formula = data.dist ~ TP * Treatment, data = fac.data, permutations = 999, method = "bray", strata = fac.data$Tank)
             Df SumOfSqs      R2      F Pr(>F)  
TP            3 0.040207 0.28861 2.8343  0.057 .
Treatment     1 0.020644 0.14819 4.3658  0.101  
TP:Treatment  2 0.012260 0.08800 1.2963  0.245  
Residual     14 0.066200 0.47520                
Total        20 0.139311 1.00000
```

The PERMANOVA results for when the samples are reordered (in both data frames) to TP 1, 3, 5, 0 (but nothing else changes) are

```
Permutation test for adonis under reduced model
Terms added sequentially (first to last)
Blocks:  strata 
Permutation: free
Number of permutations: 999

adonis2(formula = data.dist ~ TP * Treatment, data = master, permutations = 999, method = "bray", strata = fac.data$Tank)
             Df SumOfSqs      R2      F Pr(>F)   
TP            3 0.040207 0.28861 2.8343  0.002 **
Treatment     1 0.020644 0.14819 4.3658  0.010 **
TP:Treatment  2 0.012260 0.08800 1.2963  0.231   
Residual     14 0.066200 0.47520                 
Total        20 0.139311 1.00000
```

I will attach my relevant code below, but in summary, for TP 1, 3, and 5 samples were collected under high temperature and ambient temperatures (control) and grown in tanks. TP 0 are field samples collected from the same coral colonies to get a baseline of any tank effects. I am analyzing proteomic, metabolomic, transcriptomic, and 16S amplicon sequence data and treating each the same after their respective normalization. I am additionally taking the square root of each value and then creating a dissimilarity matrix.

This is only the code pertaining to the PERMANOVA test, which is part of a larger analysis, which is why there are so many packages, but I'll show each just in case it matters. The R version is 4.2.0.

```
# Load libraries
library(magrittr)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
library(seacarb) 
library(matrixStats)
library(vegan)
library(RVAideMemoire)
library(lme4)
library(ape)
library(emmeans)
library(gridExtra)
library(multcompView)
library(plotrix)
library(reshape2)
library(ggpubr)
library(sva, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(mixOmics)
library(ggforce)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
library(gapminder)
library(htmlwidgets)

# Set seed
set.seed(54321)

### Format data for downstream analyses ###

# Filter for data with total counts >= ____
filtered.data <- data.df %>% 
            replace(is.na(.), 0) %>%
            dplyr::mutate(sum = rowSums(across(where(is.numeric))))
filtered.data <- filtered.data[!(filtered.data$sum <= 100),]
filtered.data$sum <- NULL

### Format samplesInfo for downstream analyses ###
master <- master %>%
            mutate_all(as.character)
master$TP <- as.factor(master$TP)
master$Treatment <- as.factor(master$Treatment)
master$Tank <- as.factor(master$Tank)

str(master)


### PERMANOVA ###

# Transpose df
t.filtered.data <- t(filtered.data)
t.filtered.data <- as.data.frame(t.filtered.data)

# Complete dataframe for PERMANOVA
fac.data <- merge(master, t.filtered.data, by = 0)
rownames(fac.data) <- fac.data[[1]]
fac.data[[1]] <- NULL

# Use square root or proportions to minimize influence of most abundant groups
sum(is.na(t.filtered.data))
data.mat <- sqrt(data.mat)
sum(is.na(data.mat))
which(is.na(data.mat), arr.ind = TRUE) #where NA's are located, if present

# Create a dissimilarity matrix (vegan)
data.dist <- vegdist(data.mat, method = 'bray')

# Run perMANOVA (vegan)
mod.data <- adonis2(data.dist ~  Treatment * TP, data = fac.data, permutations = 999, strata = fac.data$Tank, method = 'bray')
mod.data
```

If anyone could please help me understand what is happening and how to correct for this so I get accurate PERMANOVA results, I would appreciate it greatly! Also, if I haven't included any pertinent information, please let me know. This is my first question on any of these sites. I have spent 2 days trying to figure out the reason, but I cannot find a definite explanation.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please read the documentation: it is intended to answer potential questions. In this case, you should go to argument `by`. Quoting from `help(adonis2)`:

> by: ‘by = "terms"’ will assess significance for each term
> (sequentially from first to last), setting ‘by = "margin"’
> will assess the marginal effects of the terms (each marginal
> term analysed in a model with all other variables), and ‘by =
> NULL’ will assess the overall significance of all terms
> together. The arguments is passed on to ‘anova.cca’.

The default is to analyse terms sequentially which is the same as in the standard `anova` of base **R**.

Comment: I did read the documentation, and I can't say I fully understand how to properly use "by = ___" or why the sample order changes the results so much. If you (or anyone else) could please explain more or provide links that explain with more detail so I better understand for this data set, as well as future experiments, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Because the explanatory variables are correlated and explain partly the same thing. Then the next variable has less to explain, because previous already explained a part. If you swap the order of variables, the one that explains more will change. This is the same in `anova(lm(...))`. If X1 explains component (AB), and X2 component (BC), ~X1+X2 decomposes as (AB) + (C), and ~X2+X1 as (BC) + (A). Marginal model would give only (A) for X1 and (C) for X2 and neglect shared (B) but be order-invariant.

Comment: I'm not having trouble with the order of factors in the formula. The order of SAMPLES in my datasheets change the PERMANOVA results. TP 0 was collected after all other TPs, so I had those samples last in my sample information and sequence data frames (the order was 1, 3, 5, 0), but if I move those samples first (0, 1, 3, 5), I get completely different results. I'm assuming it has to do with how the data is shuffled with permutations, but I am not exactly sure how to perform the PERMANOVA correctly so that either the sample order doesn't matter or the samples are in the correct order.

Comment: I should also add that my TPs are not evenly spaced, but I do have an equal number of samples for each TP and condition.

Comment: I had a closer look at your results, and it seems that you have **no** differences in results! All statistics are equal – except the *permutation*-based _P_-values, and even these are not too different. Permutation tests are *randomized* and there is no "correct order" for a random vector. Increase the number of permutations if you want to have less variable _P_-values.

Comment: Alrighty, thank you for clarifying and checking so closely! You've made me very happy! Thank you, again!

Comment: You can use `permustats` to extract the permutation results, and its display methods (such as `densityplot`)  to see if you have irregular or multimodal distributions from permutations. These could explain variable _P_-values. See documentation `help(permustats)` in **vegan**.